# How to separate list in rows of x

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help separating a list in rows of x (inputed by user). I can't seem to be able to do so.

Here's what I have so far:

```
# List of random integers between 0-100
def createGrades(amt): 
    import random
    myGrades = random.sample(range(0,100), amt)
    return myGrades


# To list myGrades neatly in rows of 6
myGrades = createGrades(10)
def printRows(myGrades, amtPerRow):
    n=0
    for i in range(0+n, amtPerRow+n):
    print(myGrades, end='\n')  #Stuck at this part
```

How can I make this work? I tried doing an i in range, but it just spits out amtPerRow's of the myGrades list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of issues here. The first is that the print statement is not indented (and thus not actually in your `for` loop). Second, the range is not properly specified. If `amtPerRow` were 6, range would be (0, 6), which as you mentioned would only print out elements 0-6 in the list.

If I understand your question correctly, you'd want to print out every grade, but add a line break every 6 grades. This is a modulo operation.

Here's an example that prints out the rows as CSV (comma-separated values), since I don't know what delimiter you'd want between items--it's not specified in your question.

```
def printRows(myGrades, amtPerRow):
    for i, grade in enumerate(myGrades):
        print(grade, end="")
        if (i + 1) % amtPerRow == 0:
            print("\n", end="")
        else:
            print(",", end="")
```

Which for `grades = [82, 34, 81, 79, 31, 18, 7, 67, 13, 25]` gives me:

```
>>> printRows(grades, 6)
82,34,81,79,31,18
7,67,13,25,
```

---

I'm assuming Python 3, given your print statements, but if not, you can use:

```
from ___future__ import print_function
```

to get the print function here. Alternatively, use the comma syntax in Python 2 (`print grade,`) to not have a line break after each print statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(1+len(myGrades)//6):
    print myGrades[i*6:(i+1)*6]
```